# jquery datetime picker not showing select drop down for time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetime picker control in my application. I want to change the time selection from Slider to Select drop down. I am using this code to define my control.

```
<input id="addEventEndDate" type="text" name="addEventEndDate" />
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    $('#addEventEndDate').datetimepicker({
                        controlType: 'select',
                        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
                    });
                </script>
```

But this is not changing the time picker from slider to drop down.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching it was found that SELECT option was introduced in a later version of dattimepicker than the one I was using. I was using 0.6.2 version while the current version is 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously I can't find anything wrong in your code.Please check out this fiddle and replace the

http://jsfiddle.net/VMg42/

```
$("#timepicker").timepicker(
        {

        minDate: 0,
        timeFormat: "hh:mm TT"
 });
```

with

```
                $('#addEventEndDate').datetimepicker({
                    controlType: 'select',
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
                });
```

and run..also change the html part.It works fine.Please check it.. :)

Comment: Thanks for help, but problem was with the version of datetimepicker, pls. see my post below.